# Using multiple params in RMarkdown YAML fields

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose I have `df` as my dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(title = c("Hello there", "Good morning", "Good afternoon", "Good evening"),
                 date = c("4 Jan 2019", "6 Jan 2019", "10 Jan 2019", "14 Jan 2019"))
```

I would like to use params to reproduce reports for each date and on the yaml have both title and date.

My `template.Rmd`

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
params:
  title: "Hello there"
  date: "4 Jan 2019"
title: "`r params$title`"
date: "`r params$date`"
---

On `r params$date`, she said `r params$title`.
```

My R script for reproduction:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

title <- df$title

reports <- tibble(
    filename = str_c(title, ".html"),
    params = map(title, ~list(title = .))
)

reports %>%
    select(output_file = filename, params) %>%
    pwalk(rmarkdown::render, input = "template.Rmd", output_dir = "output")
```

Thank you.

Comment: If I read your core correctly, you are not passing `params` to `rmarkdown::render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File `template.Rmd`:**

````
---
title: "`r params$title`"
date: "`r params$date`"
params:
  title: no # default
  date: no  # default
author: "Darren Tsai"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

On `r params$date`, she said `r params$title`.
````

---

**R script:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(title = c("Hello there", "Good morning", "Good afternoon", "Good evening"),
                 date = c("4 Jan 2019", "6 Jan 2019", "10 Jan 2019", "14 Jan 2019"))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(filename = str_c(title, ".html"))

df2

#            title        date            filename
# 1    Hello there  4 Jan 2019    Hello there.html
# 2   Good morning  6 Jan 2019   Good morning.html
# 3 Good afternoon 10 Jan 2019 Good afternoon.html
# 4   Good evening 14 Jan 2019   Good evening.html

df2 %>%
  pwalk(~ rmarkdown::render("template.Rmd", output_file = ..3,
                            params = list(title = ..1, date = ..2)))
```

`..1`, `..2`, and `..3` represent **title, date,** and **filename** in `df2`.

**Note:** What you set in the argument `params` of `render()` must be declared in YAML, so in my Rmd file I set default values `no` to `title` and `date` under `params`.

---

Check the four HTML file:

[image]

Comment: This worked exactly as expected. The only thing I added to `rmarkdown::render` was `output_dir = "output"` to keep the folder organized.

Comment: I moved from the sample data to the main dataset and after 50 files, I got this error:
`Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 1, column 49`

I assume this may be missing data entries but i checked through and did not find missing values.

Comment: @Kranja I'm sorry...I don't have your file and dataset so I cannot understand what happens just from your comment. I think this is a different issue from the original question so you could post it as a new one.

Comment: There was a missing entry and the script did not have an error handling option like `tryCatch`.